# Is it possible turn the Dirichlet ring into a Banach algebra?

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

The set of all arithmetic functions $f:\mathbb{Z}^{+}\to\mathbb{C}$, under pointwise addition and Dirichlet convolution, is a commutative ring, not all functions are Dirichlet invertible.

So my question is:
To what subset of the arithmetic functions and under what norms can one attach a Banach algebra structure to the Dirichlet ring? Is it even possible?

Comment: The set of $f$ such that $f(1) \not= 0$ is not closed under addition even if you throw in the zero function, so you do not obtain a field.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will update the question. I understand this doesn't impact my question otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact $$\|a\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n n^{-\sigma}|$$ is a bit more natural than my other answer.. It gives the Banach algebra of absolutely convergent Dirichlet series on $\Re(s)\ge \sigma$. There are [interesting theorems](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2032683?seq=1) about its invertible elements.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict to the convergent Dirichlet series (those with polynomially bounded coefficients) then $$\|a\|=4\sup_n |a_n| e^{-n}$$ should be a ring norm, as for some $n$

$$\|a\ast b\|=4 |\sum_{d| n}a_d b_{n/d}|e^{-n} \le 4  \sum_{d|n} \frac1{4} \|a\| e^{n/d}\frac1{4} \|b\| e^d e^{-n}\le \frac1{4} \|a\|\|b\|(1 + 2 e^{-n}\sum_{d=2}^{\sqrt n} e^{n/d}e^{d})$$ $$\le \frac1{4} \|a\|\|b\| (1 + 2 \sum_{d=2}^{\sqrt n} e^{d-n/2})\le \|a\|\|b\| $$

**The completion is clearly the Banach algebra of formal Dirichlet series with $O(e^n)$ coefficients.** It is an integral domain.

Note that the inverse of a convergent Dirichlet series $k^{-s}+\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty c_n n^{-s}$ exists as a convergent generalized  Dirichlet series $k^s \sum_{l=0}^\infty (-\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty c_n (n/k)^{-s})^l=\sum_{u\in \Bbb{Q}_{> 0}} d_u u^{-s}$, the obtained ring is a field. Does anyone want to check how $\|a\ast b\|\le \|a\|\|b\|$ fails when extending the norm to those generalized Dirichlet series ?

Comment: Thank you very very much!